# update dataframe from pandas series based on comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

[image]

I have calculated tweet_final_score using

```
def divide_two_cols(tweet_dataframe):

    return  tweet_dataframe["tweet_basic_score"] / tweet_dataframe['source_mean']

    y = tweet_dataframe.groupby('tweet_source').apply(divide_two_cols)
```

The issue is I am getting pandas series object. I want to update the tweet_final_score in the pandas data frame.

The out put of y is somehing like this.

```
       1     0.180517
              16    0.876128
              17    0.710395
              18    1.837068
              19    1.395892
   6     1.333333
              12    1.000000
              13    0.250000
              14    1.416667
              15    1.000000
       0     1.759259
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify solution - `groupby` here is not necessary:

```
tweet_dataframe['new'] = tweet_dataframe["tweet_basic_score"] / tweet_dataframe['source_mean']
```